# Java - propagating a threadlocal by wrapping a runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, delegates

My aim is to use a thread pool together with a thread local. I cannot use `InheritableThreadLocal` because the thread data is different per user and there a couple of parallel users at any time.

So I need to push the thread local down from the mother thread to the children.

I use guava so I want to get listenable futures back. Below is my implementation. Please look at the execute function where the logic happens.

My question is what could go wrong here?

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import myorg.MyService;
import myorg.ThreadData;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService;

public class ListeningDecorator extends AbstractListeningExecutorService {
    private final ExecutorService delegate;

    ListeningDecorator(final ExecutorService delegate) {
        this.delegate = checkNotNull(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean awaitTermination(final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return this.delegate.awaitTermination(timeout, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean isShutdown() {
        return this.delegate.isShutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean isTerminated() {
        return this.delegate.isTerminated();
    }

    @Override
    public final void shutdown() {
        this.delegate.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public final List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        return this.delegate.shutdownNow();
    }

    @Override
    public final void execute(final Runnable command) {
        final ThreadData threadData = MyService.getThreadData();
        if (threadData == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("threadData is null");
        }
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyService.setThreadData(threadData);
                command.run();

            }
        };

        this.delegate.execute(runnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be good to revert the `ThreadLocal` changes in the worker thread as soon as `command.run()` finished (using `try-finally`). This would have the following advantages:

1. If your `ExecutorService delegate` (provided to the constructor) is also used somwhere else for different tasks, then currently these tasks would be affected by the changes you make to the ThreadLocals as part of `ListeningDecorator.execute`. For example:

   ```java
   ExecutorService delegateExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
   ListeningDecorator listeningExecutor = new ListeningDecorator(delegateExecutor);

   // Sets MyService thread data
   Future<?> future = listeningExecutor.submit(() -> {
       ...
   });
   future.get();

   // In different thread: Directly use delegateExecutor
   delegateExecutor.execute(() -> {
       // Would still have MyService thread data even though this was submitted
       // by different thread
       ...
   });
   ```

   If the MyService thread data changes were reverted as soon as `command.run()` finished, then this would not be an issue.
2. Reverting the changes might allow the garbage collector to collect MyService thread data earlier. Otherwise it might linger around indefinitely if `ExecutorService delegate` reuses threads.